# check occupied grid-elements

Tags: actionscript-3, grid

I created a visual grid of sprites which are stored in an Array1.
Some of those sprites got an image placed on it.
Now I would like to drag another image on an empty grid-element.
Special case:
Several images are dragged at the same time for being placed.
Therefore a drag-container holds also an Array2 of those dragged images.
As soon as the mouse goes up, the images of Array2 should be placed on empty grid elements of Array1.

My question: How do I check if a sprite of Array1 is occupied or not?
While several images have been dragged, every image should be placed one grid-element below the previous(y-axis down). In this process it could happen that you place an image on an empty grid-element, but because several are placed below each other the next grid-element could be occupied and therefore the currently placed image should be placed to the next free grid-element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make a boolean array (let's cal it `boolarr`), containing `true` on i-th place if i-th Sprite of a grid already has an image. otherwise `boolarr[i]` is `false`. You should store `boolarr` in grid class, and change it each time images are added.

So, here's possible solution. We drop several images on `i`-th place. Let's find n next free spries

```
function getFreeSprites(n: int, i: position) {
    var result = [];
    while (result.length < n) {
        if (!boolarr[i]) result.push(i);
        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

array returned by the function will contain indexes of next n free sprites, after that you can attach images to them.

Hope that helps!